# Get Groupon Deals by tag using Groupon API

Tags: php, api, groupon

I am playing around with the Groupon API and I would like to get a list of deals based on a specific tag.

Using the www.apigee.com console, I am doing a GET request on this URL:
https://api.groupon.com/v2/deals.json?division_id=new-york&tag=Arcade&client_id={myId}

However, the response I am getting appears to just be all the deals for that division (In this case, New York).

Here is a link to the relevant API documentation: 
http://sites.google.com/site/grouponapiv2/api-resources/deals

Comment: I was told from others that the Groupon API does not allow you to filter. You need to first make an API call and get the full response back and then you can filter based on the deals tag.

Answer (score 1):

You can't.
The request parameters do not include tag.

You can use [Yipit](http://yipit.com/about/api/)'s api to filter by tag.